# Stormpath how to stop a user from registering

Tags: node.js, stormpath

I have a stormpath app on my Porfolio website which I use for logging to update my blog/ projects list. I want to remove the ability for a user to register (which they could do by visiting `site.com/register`).

How do I do this?

I'm running on Node.js and Express.js if that helps

If you need anymore information please ask.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using the [express-stormpath](https://docs.stormpath.com/nodejs/express/) library (which I think you are), you can disable the registration functionaly by entering the following middleware setting:

```
app.use(stormpath.init(app, {
  enableRegistration: false  // this disables all registration functionality
}));
```

That should do it =)